# Landscape mode for Xcode using storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, uiinterfaceorientation, uistoryboard

I´m making an app for a Zoo, and it is very simple, but because at fisrt I tried to make it with code and using xcode 3.2, but I had some problems so I started it with Xcode 4.3 and am trying it with the storyboards.

My question is, how could I put all the app in landscape mode? I mean I already set it in the infoplist: the initial interface orientation, and then in the .m file I changed the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

But it doesn´t work. When I add a tabbarcontroller and link it all the views become portrait. The first one if I rotate it it does give me the landscape but all the others are always in portrait, so what can I do?

Comment: When using `UITabBarController`, all `viewControllers` in it, must support the orientation you want. It means, they all must return YES for landscape. Did you take this into consideration?

Comment: What @Canopus said, plus the same goes for UINavigationController contained viewControllers.

Comment: Actually I only have one class, everything it´s linked by the storyboards, so do I have to make a class for the tabbar controller as well?? I mean it works fine, just this problem with the interface orientation.

Comment: Thank you guys for getting interested.

Comment: If all your view controllers are in storyboard, and they are linked to the `UITabBarController` (as @Till said, including `UIViewController`s and `UINavigationController`s), then yes, you need to subclass them all, in order to over ride the `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method and return yes for supported orientations.

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out? Can you share your solution? tx

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add tabbar controller on storyboard, in attribute inspector of tab bar you have orientation that is on inferred by default, change it to Landscape. But is better you set orientation from summary tab of project to Landscape Right. it lets your up come up on Right landscape.